# How to organize connection to different database with Entity Framework 4?

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, entity-framework-4

How to organize connection to different database with Entity Framework 4 by means of settings?

For example: one client works with Oracle, another with SQL Server. Database structure is equal. I need setting param to change database type

Comment: Which flavor of EF are you using - Model-first, Database-first, Code-first?

Answer (score 0):

When using XML-mapping (both Database-First and Model-First approaches) a solution with resource splitting (one CSDL, one MSL, many SSDL) and different connection strings is required. An example of such approach is as follows: [EFQuerySamples from Microsoft](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFQuerySamples/), illustrating interaction with different SQL Server and SQL Server Compact versions, and its modified version [EFQuerySamples from Devart](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/efquerysamples.html) that supports Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite in addition to SQL Server.

When using fluent mapping (Code-First approach with DbContext utilization) multiple resources are not required, but some peculiarities of certain databases and EF-providers must be taken into account (the absense of the "dbo" schema, etc.). An example of such approach is as follows: [Code-First sample for SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite](http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/entity-framework-code-first-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite.html) .